# Angularjs with SharePoint vs Knockout Js with SharePoint

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, knockout.js

compare and contrast Angularjs with SharePoint vs Knockoutjs with SharePoint

Answer (score 1):

Acording the number of github contributions I would choose angular:

**[AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js) (5720 commits):**
[image]

**[KnockoutJS](https://github.com/knockout/knockout) (1224 commits):**
[image]

From the Sharepoint perspective there is any other difference or limitation.

Comment: Thanks but i was looking for some user experience of using this js with sharepoint, things that they expect but wasnt there kind of stuff

Comment: @007ruwan i compared AngularJS vs KnockoutJS from SPA point of view -> now you have only AngularJS and Sharepoint -> half of job done :)

Comment: @007ruwan BTW: why do you want to use sharepoint? I'm just curious.

Comment: I'm moving to SharePoint 2013 from 2010, i have seen almost everyone use knockoutJS, but as i was searching the net and went through angular js and as people praise about angular js i wonder why majority does not move towards angular but stick in knockout

Comment: @user2358851 because MS promotes knockout